# InRelease- Release Management Licence issue using with TFS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msdn, ms-release-management

We installed the latest version of Release Management from MSDN and connected it to our TFS 2012 Server. The migration to TFS 2013 is scheduled to a later point.

After one week we are getting the following error in the logs:

License for Release Management Server for Team Foundation Server 2013 has expired.

Is a TFS 2013 server mandatory for the usage of the new Version of Release Management? In our case it was working for a week without any problems with the TFS 2012.

I didn't see any pages in the Client where a licence can be entered.

We stuck with our Deployment. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Posted same question at below link also.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/24655842-37a6-4be5-9edb-e31cc0dc74fd/release-manager-2013-preview-inrelease-connecting-to-tfs-2012?forum=tfsbuild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Licensing is on a per-deployment server/CPU core basis. Microsoft has [licensing info](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/how-to-buy-release-management-vs) up on MSDN, but it's still a little bit confusing at the moment.

I suspect that you downloaded a trial version that has expired. If you have an Ultimate MSDN subscription, then you have a free license, per the licensing page.

Release Management works with TFS2010, 2012, and 2013 -- the licensing is the same for all of them, so it's not that you're connecting it to TFS 2012.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortnuately the ISO file that we used was downloaded using MSDN Ultimate subscription, therefore the confusion came up. We understand the licensing page that with an Ultimate subscription we have this free license. However, it stopped to work after excately 1 week (so not even the 90 days that are claimed on the trial version).

Any idea what else we can check?

Thanks!

Comment: That's strange, then. I've installed it via the MSDN ISO before and never seen that behavior pop up. How many deployers do you have installed?

Comment: even that's strange for us...we have installed 4 deployers on various target server.

Comment: That might explain it -- the license that comes with MSDN Ultimate covers "two physical processors and up to two endpoints (virtual machines)". It might be worth having a chat with a Microsoft rep to untangle the licensing.

Comment: @mdJawed do you have any other VS skus installed on your Release Management Server machine?